# MYSQL UPDATE TEXT field not working

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I'm trying to update a TEXT field in a MYSQL table. I can't get the UPDATE query to work, even though the original INSERT attempt works fine when the user doesn't exist.

The purpose of the function is to INSERT new row if the user doesn't exist yet, and to UPDATE the textColumn (that always contains a JSON) if the user already exists in the table.

My code:

```
let first = 'jake';
let last = 'mcdonald';

let first_json = JSON.stringify({a:7, b:7});

let second_json = JSON.stringify({a:'updated'});

const row = {
  name: first,
  last_name: last,
  textColumn: first_json,
}

db.query(`SELECT * FROM tableName 
          WHERE name="${first}" 
          AND last_name="${last}"`, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (result.length < 1) {
      db.query(`INSERT INTO tableName SET ?`, row, (err, result) => {
        console.log('NEW ROW CREATED: ', result);
      })
    } else if (result.length > 0) {
      console.log('ROW EXISTS');
      db.query(`UPDATE tableName 
                SET textColumn=${second_json} 
                WHERE name="${first}" 
                AND last_name="${last}"`, (err, result) => {
          console.log('UPDATED: ', result);
        }
      )
    }
  }
)
```

the `else if` section is what is giving me issues: I reach the inside `console.log('ROW EXISTS')` but the Update query logs "undefined".

The same UPDATE query works if I try to `UPDATE tableName SET name="someNewName" WHERE last_name="original_last_name"`, but nothing happens when I try to UPDATE the textColumn.

Comment: **WARNING**: To avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) always escape *any* arbitrary data in your query by using [placeholder values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values). You're not escaping anything here correctly which is going to be a serious problem.

Comment: It's not clear what `SET ?` is intending here. That's highly unlikely to work.

Comment: `SET ?` works fine, the only part of the code that does not work as intended is the block inside the `else if`

Comment: Nothing about this is likely to work at all given how inadequate that escaping is. Fix that and your problems will likely be resolved. JSON uses `"` as a delimiter, it *must* be escaped properly.

Comment: Thnx, using '?' and then using array as second argument of the query to pass the values worked.